# Rails Windows - No Coffeescript option in "new" command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, sass

I just installed Ruby and Rails via RailsInstaller and it seems that coffeescript and SCSS are not installed.

I want to create my project using `rails new` command but no options refering to them:

```
fmarcoux@freud MINGW64 ~/RubymineProjects
$ rails new -h
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps], [--no-skip-keeps]                  # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
      [--skip-spring], [--no-skip-spring]                # Don't install Spring application preloader
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
      [--skip-turbolinks], [--no-skip-turbolinks]        # Skip turbolinks gem
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                                          # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc], [--no-no-rc]                            # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.

fmarcoux@freud MINGW64 ~/RubymineProjects
$
```

I installed Coffee and SCSS via `gem install coffee-rails` and `gem install scss-rails`.

But still not appearing as seen on the photo (the pic was taken after install, no changes.) (yes, I tried to restart the Git Bash)

Am I the only one with this issue? If no, how to fix it. I need SCSS and Coffee for me project!

Edit: When I create the project (with --pretend), here's the output:

```
$ rails new --pretend helloworld
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
```

There's no CoffeeScript assets nor SCSS!

Comment: Text is almost always better than images when supplying textual information.

Comment: I'm going to repeat once again a solid advice of many Rails developers out there: **use a virtual machine fitted with a Unix-like OS, that will save you a lot of time**. I personally recommend Linux Mint + VirtualBox in Seamless Mode, friendly enough and works well enough with Ruby ecosystem.

Comment: CS and Sass are the *default*, aren't they? I'm not aware you have to supply any options; I don't have the options either (under OS X or Linux) and everything I have uses CS/Sass.

Comment: ...and yes, you could at least try creating a project and see that they're right there, in the template app :)

Comment: @D-side I tried, not there.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code or errors.  (see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Please answer. Understood for the image but I can't change it right now. Still the image has good resolution!

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux [sure it is](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f18ea14c893cb5c9f04d4fda9661126758332b5/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb). Generic `rails` help won't tell you much, create the project and look at its Gemfile. If the entries you need are not there, just add them in. There are tons of useful gems Rails doesn't add by default, that doesn't mean you can't add them into an existing project.

Comment: @D-side I edited for you to see the output. No `.coffee` or `.scss` files are generated. And adding the gem is a thing, but I will need to create files and structure, which the generator does for me.

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux and it shouldn't, and folder structure is not different. Now create an app and execute this: `rails g controller Home index` and see what it generates.

Comment: @D-side Indeed, it generates .coffee and .scss. Now how can I configure the app to use only these? Like no .css file anywhere, not even the `application.css` which is generated on `rails new`...

Post it as answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: I don't think there is a way other than using/making a different generator. And it's not like you need that anyway, `application.*` assets are meant only to list assets for precompilation, not to contain actual code.